# CredentialUnavailableError: Please run 'az login' to set up an account

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-cli

Hi I'm getting this error when running commands with a new cluster. When I run a script with the old cluster, I don't get any errors but when I use the new one, I get this error..
Have anyone faced the same issue?
Should I run this az login in Azure CLI?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/keyvault/secrets/_shared/challenge_auth_policy.py in _handle_challenge(self, request, challenge)
    135             # azure-identity credentials require an AADv2 scope but the challenge may specify an AADv1 resource
    136             scope = challenge.get_scope() or challenge.get_resource() + "/.default"
--> 137             self._token = self._credential.get_token(scope)
    138 
    139         # ignore mypy's warning because although self._token is Optional, get_token raises when it fails to get a token

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/identity/_internal/decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     25         [0;32mdef wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
     26             try:
---> 27                 token = fn(*args, **kwargs)
     28                 _LOGGER.info("%s succeeded", qualified_name)
     29                 return token

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/azure_cli.py in get_token(self, *scopes, **kwargs)
     56         output, error = _run_command(COMMAND_LINE.format(resource))
     57         if error:
---> 58             raise error
     59 
     60         token = parse_token(output)

CredentialUnavailableError: Please run 'az login' to set up an account
```

Comment: can you share full stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CredentialUnavailableError: Please run 'az login' to set up an account.

As per the error you are not authenticated with the Azure. This issue is caused by Azure CLI method of authentication.

**To resolve this, you need to execute following commands in the Databricks notebook:**

```bash
%sh
pip install azure-cli
az login
az account set  --subscription  <Subscription Id>
```

It will first install azure CLI on the head node then `az login` will login you in your specific azure account and `az account set  --subscription` will set the context to use specific subscription.

**My execution:**
[image]